Query request count for a each endpoint in rest controller
I have Dynatrace agent attached to my Spring-Boot app with multiple rest controllers. Each rest controller has multiple API endpoints.
I have the following query to get total request counts for rest controller with entityId = "SERVICE-A9876543210" (for all API endpoints)
GET https://{environmentId}.live.dynatrace.com/api/v2/metrics/query
?metricSelector=builtin:service.requestCount.total
&resolution=1m
&from=-10m
&to=now
&entitySelector=entityId("SERVICE-A9876543210")

How can I alter this query to get request count for each API in given rest controller?

You can change the entitySelector, there are multiple options.
You could add all the services manually by ID, use a Tag that's on all the services or select them by the Process Group if you want all services of that PG.
EDIT: Misread the question. If you want information about the request counts of all endpoints of a given controller, that's not available as a metric by default. Only on service level.
You can create a custom service metric that is split by the request name to get what you want.

Custom service metric works like a charm. Thank you!
